# Server Data Overflow

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I work with Firebase and fill UserProperties with what player character wears(helmet, ring, boots). I have recently changed a name of a user property and now in BigQuery our analytics see that there is an old name(BootsEquipmentItemName) and the new one(BootsItemName)

I suggest that because of that renaming we encountered an overflow of data(max 25 user properties) and can't see other user properties(we have 24 of them)

My question is how can we remove old names from a BigQuery/Firebase server correctly and without loosing all analytics data?

I have already asked Google Analytics the same question

Comment: Can you elaborate on this issue - *overflow of data*? Also, changing a name is just a matter of reading the old data in, and writing it back out with the new name (You cannot directly change property names). I believe the analytics data would be affected by that change since it's an entirely new property name.

Comment: By "Overflow of data" I understand that we have reached a limit of 25 max parameters for User Properties. On analytics data we saw parameters with the old names alongside with new names but we don't need parameters with old names and my question was, how can we remove them?

Comment: I don't think that's the intent of the user property; it's really for things like language preference or geographic location; values that don't change frequently. Storing a players armor (helmet, ring etc) would/should be stored separately. Firestore or the RTDB was not specified but if you need to 'change' a field name within a document, you would read the document, get the field value, add the newly named field with that value and remove the old field and then write it out. That should all be done within a transaction to ensure completeness.